# How can i store a string value inside a html div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple messenger for my school project

I need to store id number of each chat message inside himself (which is a div tag) and I want to access this value from JavaScript with id or name of div.

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried so far? It would be useful for us to help you, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store arbitrary data in custom attributes.

```
<div id="id1" any="value">

document.getElementById("id1").getAttribute("any");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let assume a div tag's id equals to NumberID ( `<div id="NumberID"></div>` )

If you are gonna wanna use javascript,

```
var NumberID = document.getElementById("NumberID").innerHTML;
```

Then you can get the result from the NumberID variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
divID = 'the id of your div';
content = 'the content you want in that div';
div = document.getElementById(divID);
div.innerHTML(content);
```

Documentation:

[.getElementByID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

[.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to use for storage is an array cause it's way faster than the DOM and the DOM isn't your storage. Here a small code example how to use an array to store stuff, extract and foreach

```
// declaring the array
const messages = [];

// can be automated to restructure incoming dataformat
function incoming(nodeId, msgId, msg) {
    messages.push({
        // you can store the html node directly for faster access
        // even better if you pass the node as a parameter
        // "node": document.getElementById(nodeId),
        "node": nodeId,
        "msgId": msgId,
        "msg": msg
    })
    // do other stuff here example:
    // appendMsg();
}

// incoming messages
incoming("box-1", 25823, "hi, whats up??")
incoming("box-2", 25824, "not much...")
incoming("box-3", 25825, "wanna learn JS?")
let searchResult = messages.find((ele) => {
    // use return ele.node.id == `box-1` if you store the elements and want to find an element
    return ele.node == "box-2"  
})
console.log(searchResult)

// using map to print the text of all messages
messages.map(ele => console.log(ele.msg))
```